# Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)

Tags: string, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I want to have a multiline string in Fortran code. I tried to do it this way:

```
print *, "Line 1&
  &line 2"
```

But it gives me syntax errors when compiling the file `gfortran myfile.f`:

> Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)

How can I have multiline strings in a clean way?

Comment: Rename as `myfile.f90`.

Comment: Do you want to split the character literal or the output of the program over two lines?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt While not a requirement, that would be handy too!

Comment: There are essentially two different possible questions here: "how do I split character literals over source lines in fixed-form source?" and "why is this supposedly valid free-form source code not compiling".  It seems the answer desired is to that latter one?  [This is the renaming as `.f90` point.]

Comment: And is much the same as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23883368).  There may even be a question it's a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be easily done using string concatenation. Example (in a free-form .f90 file):

```
write(*,'(A)') 'Line 1'//&
               'line 2'//&
               'and so forth'
```

Comment: This isn't wrong but it's totally unnecessary.  It has the same effect as OP's original fragment had that been compiled as free-form source.

Comment: Fair enough, but I like this way better since it is obvious what is happening. The original is not clear to a novice (and perhaps some experts) as to whether or not the spaces or the '&' symbol on the second line ends up in the string.